# Python: Is it better to have many variables or to store their values in lists?

Tags: performance, python-2.7, list, variables

I am aware that this may seem like a vague question, but I wonder if (e.g. in Python) it is preferable to store multiple values in separate variables, or to store them in logical groups (lists, arrays...).

In my precise case I am supposed to translate a Matlab code into Python 2.7. It is a physically based model that digests 8 input variables and creates two large lists as output. I found that the original model has a huge amount of variables that are calculated on the way (>100). As a rule of thumb: if one calculation is accessed more than once, it is stored in a new variable. Demonstrative example:

```
x = 3
y = 5
x2 = x**2
z = x2 + exp(y)
zz = (y+x)/x2
```

x^2 is used two times (for the calculation of z and zz), so it is stored as x2. Is this really faster than letting python calculate x**2 two times? Also, would it be faster if I stored them in lists? Like this:

```
x = [3, 5]
z = x[0]**2 + exp(x[1])
zz = sum(x)/x[0]**2
```

The organisation of variables in lists may come at the expense of readibility of the code, but I would gladly take that if it makes my code run faster.

Comment: You have the code; profile it and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no performance advantage I can see to keeping it in a list. On the contrary, putting it in a list makes it slower:

```
>>>  %%timeit
...: x = 3
...: y = 5
...: x2 = x**2
...: z = x2 + exp(y)
...: zz = (y+x)/x2
...: 
337 ns ± 1.87 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

>>>  %%timeit
...: x = [3, 5]
...: z = x[0]**2 + exp(x[1])
...: zz = sum(x)/x[0]**2
...: 
716 ns ± 4.87 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Now part of that is because you are calculating `x**2` twice in the list condition, but even fixing that issue doesn't make the list version faster:

```
>>>  %%timeit
...: x = [3, 5]
...: x0 = x[0]**2
...: z = x0 + exp(x[1])
...: zz = sum(x)/x0
...: 
502 ns ± 12.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

If you compare about performance, another big issue is that you are defining ints then converting them to floats. In MATLAB, `x = 5` makes a float, while in python it makes an integer. It is much faster to do everything with floats from the beginning, which you can do by just putting a `.` or `.0` at the end of the number:

```
>>>  %%timeit
...: x = 3.0
...: y = 5.0
...: x2 = x**2.0
...: z = x2 + exp(y)
...: zz = (y+x)/x2
...: 
166 ns ± 1.12 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

If you were to use numpy arrays rather than lists, it is even worse, because you start with a list of floats then have to do a conversion of both the numbers and the lists, then convert them back, all of which is slow:

```
>>> %%timeit
...: x = np.array([3., 5.])
...: x0 = x[0]**2.
...: z = x0 + np.exp(x[1])
...: zz = x.sum()/x0
...: 
3.22 µs ± 8.96 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

As a general rule, avoid doing type conversions wherever possible, and avoid indexing when it doesn't help readability. If you have a bunch of values, then the conversion to numpy is useful. But for just two or three it is going to hurt speed and readability.

Comment: brilliant answer, thank you! I remember people saying that numpy is quicker in mathematical tasks, so I avoided lists whenever possible. I will take care that all floats will be initialized as such. Currently 1000 model runs take 5.5sec in FORTRAN, 10.3sec in MATLAB and 11.2sec in my PYTHON code. Will have to improve that. So, thanks again :)

Comment: @offeltoffel: If my answer is what you needed please mark it as answering your question so other people can find it easily.